# CQL: Bad Request: Duplicate and incompatible conditions for column

Tags: cassandra, conditional-statements, batch-processing, cql

I am trying to understand this error message that CQL is throwing when I try to update 2 different rows with different values on same conditional columns. Doesn't CQL support that? I am wondering why CQL has this restriction (since condition applies to each row independently, why does CQL even care if the values of the condition is same or different).

```
BEGIN BATCH 
    UPDATE activities SET state='CLAIMED',version=11 WHERE key='Key1' IF version=10; 
    UPDATE activities SET state='ALLOCATED',version=2 WHERE key='Key2' IF version=1; 
APPLY BATCH;
```

gives the following error

`Bad Request: Duplicate and incompatible conditions for column version`

Is there anyway to update more than 1 row with different conditional value for each row (other than running these statements individually)?

Comment: sorry there was a typo in the second update statement. I was updating two distinct rows with different keys (just corrected my original message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only allowed to create batches for updates using the same partition key. See [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_djf_xdd_xj__batch-conditional) for details.

Comment: Yeah I read that after I sent the question. Thanks for pointing it out.